# Cannot read property 'match' on undefined on pushing to heroku

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

Tried pushing a project to heroku - got the same error when using heroku-cli and when connecting to Github.

Error Log:

```
-----> Building dependencies

       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)

       npm ERR! Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3",
    "react-social-icons": "^4.1.0",
    "react-spring": "^7.2.10"
  },
...
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.13.0"
  },
...
  "devDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.7.0"
  }
}
```

React wasn't initially in devDependencies - have that there as an attempt at fixing an earlier error.

Issue persists either way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Check package-lock.json

This issue is most likely related to your `package-lock.json`. This file causes a lot of issues, but it's recommended that you [check it into source](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json).

With that said, one of two things should fix your issue:

1. First try deleting your `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` locally, then re-install all of your dependencies: `npm i`. Try pushing to Heroku again after this is complete.
2. If the suggestion above does not work, just delete your `package-lock.json` file locally, commit your change, and try pushing to Heroku again.

Also, you should not have to list `react` as a dev dependency. You can delete that from your `package.json`.

Comment: Thanks Don!

Pushing to heroku without `package-lock.json` got things up and running! :)

Comment: @Dillon np. Please make sure to accept my answer if it helped you solve your problem.

Comment: Simply deleting `package-lock.json`, committing changes and then re-attempting deploy, also worked for me. I'd suggest making that option #1. Since this is a remote deploy, how would deleting `node_modules` locally help at all?

Answer (score 15):

I had this same issue, however none of the solutions mentioned above worked for me, I even tried to clean my remote repo, using heroku-repo plugin which by the way you can install using **heroku plugins:install heroku-repo** followed by **heroku repo:reset -a appname** to try luck with this one.

The solutions which worked for me was to disable the node_modules cache from heroku. Heroku maintains a cache directory that is persisted between builds. This cache is used to store caches for npm, yarn, and bower.

Try using the following steps.

1. **heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false**
2. now push again with - **git push heroku master**

Comment: solution worked for me. So many answers said to delete package_lock but I never pushed it to master. the p lock is in my git ignore so I knew it had to be a caching bug and when I uninstalled an old module that must have been the problem. thank you :)

Comment: Fixed for me also. Probably should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to do this `heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false` from your terminal. It was what worked for us for this same error.

Answer (score 0):

just remove lock file and try again it will work.